# Fibered product of symplectic fiber bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, symplectic-geometry

Let $P_{1}\to B$ and $P_{2}\to B$ be smooth fiber bundles over the same base manifold $B$, and let us assume that the total spaces $(P_{1},\omega_{1})$ and $(P_{2},\omega_{2})$ are symplectic manifolds with corresponding symplectic forms $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{2}$. I am looking for examples of pairs $(P_{1},\omega_{1})$ and $(P_{2},\omega_{2})$ such that the fibered product

$P = P_{1}\times_{B} P_{2}$

is a known fiber bundle, namely, the total space $P$ is an explicitly known manifold.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would $P$ carry a symplectic form? There is an obvious dimensional restriction, as $P$ need not be even dimensional.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: you are completely right, I will edit the question.

Comment: This is quite unclear. If you know $P_1 \to B$ and $P_2 \to B$, then you explicitly know $P$ as a submanifold of $P_1 \times P_2$ don't you? Can you clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: If $B$ is a Riemannian manifold, then you can pull back the symplectic structure on $TB$ via the metric isomorphism, so $P_1 = TB$ and $P_2 = T^*B$ would seem to satisfy your question. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez: I don't know $P_{1}\to B$ nor $P_{2}\to B$. I want to know explicit examples of $(P_{1},\omega_{1})$ and $(P_{2},\omega_{2})$ such that $P_{1}\times_{B} P_{2}$ is explicitly known.

Comment: @Neal: That is close to what I need. Two comments: What do you mean by "metric isomorphism"? What is the manifold $P = TB\times_{B} T^{\ast}B$?

Thanks.

Comment: @Bilateral A Riemannian metric induces an isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent bundles. The manifold $P$ should just be the Whitney sum of the two bundles, if I'm understanding your notation.